# Problem in formulas while applying protection using app script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the below script to protect a Google Sheet (script runs on opening the sheet). As per the code, the script will identify the last row with data and will protect the range upto that row. However, there are few columns which are auto computed base on formulas, in these columns formulas are applied in the entire column of the sheet, when the script runs it identifies the field with formula as field with data and hence locks the entire row till which formula exists.

I want the script to ignore the columns with formulas to be used to identify last row with data.

Further, the script locks the sheet for all users except the owner, I want to exclude few users based on email from the protection.

```
   function installedOnOpen(e) {
   const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.
   const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => 
   sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
   if (sheets.length == 0) return;
   sheets.forEach(s => {
   const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
   if (p.length > 0) {
   p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
   }
   const lastRow = s.getLastRow();
   if (lastRow != 0) {
   const newProtect = s.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, s.getMaxColumns()).protect();
   newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
   if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
   }
  });
  }
```

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. About `I want the script to ignore the columns with formulas to be used to identify last row with data.`, you have already known the columns you don't want to protect? 2. About `Further, the script locks the sheet for all users except the owner, I want to exclude few users based on email from the protection.`, you want to protect cells except for the specific columns and also you want to protect the sheet, simultaneously. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ Tanaike ... Thanks for the reply... (1) First issue, I want to protect all the columns including columns with formula, but when identifying the last row with data the columns having formula should be ignored E.g. If data is till row no 3 but formula is applied till row number 1000 then the script should consider row no. 3 as the last row to be protected. (2) In the current script the sheet is protected for all the users except owner, I want the script to lock for all except owner and specific user (based in email i.d).

Comment: @Edyphant. Do you have empty text in the formula? Like this: `=IF(A1 = "RemcoE33", "Hi Remco", "")` This will be picked up in methodes like `.getLastRow()`. Change the formula to this: `=IF(A1 = "RemcoE33", "Hi Remco", )`. Just leave the argument blank.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: @ RemcoE33 The solution offered by you works fine...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues:

There are two issues here:

1. Find the last row of data in the sheet, excluding data that was populated via formula.
2. Exclude some email addresses from the range protection, apart from the executing user.

#### Solution:

- Regarding issue #1, I'd suggest using [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api), since the field `userEnteredValue` from [CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData) will not get populated for cells that have been populated via an array formula, but which don't have a value nor formula themselves. This is done in the function `getLastRowWithUserenteredData` on the sample below.
- Regarding issue #2, just use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on [getEditors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#geteditors) to remove the desired users.

#### Code sample:

```
function installedOnOpen(e) {
  const ssId = e.source.getId();
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.
  const excludedUsers = ["email@domain.com"]; // Email addresses of excluded users, change accordingly
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  if (sheets.length == 0) return;
  sheets.forEach(s => {
    const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    if (p.length > 0) {
      p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
    }
    const lastRow = getLastRowWithUserenteredData(ssId, s.getSheetName());
    if (lastRow != 0) {
      const newProtect = s.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, s.getMaxColumns()).protect();
      const usersProtect = newProtect.getEditors().filter(e => !excludedUsers.includes(e.getEmail()));
      newProtect.removeEditors(usersProtect);
      if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  });
}

function getLastRowWithUserenteredData(ssId, sheetName) {
  const optionalArgs = {
    includeGridData: true,
    ranges: [sheetName]
  }
  const ss = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, optionalArgs);
  const { rowData } = ss.sheets.find(sh => sh.properties.title == sheetName).data[0];
  rowData.reverse(); // We want to find the last row, not the first, so we reverse the array
  const numRows = rowData.length;
  const emptyRow = rowData.findIndex(c => { // Get (first) last row with no user entered data
    return c["values"].some(v => { 
      return v && v["userEnteredValue"]; // Check if cell has no user entered data
    });
  });
  const lastRowWithUserData = numRows - emptyRow; // Total number of rows with data minus the index where we found last row without user entered data
  return lastRowWithUserData;
}
```

#### Note:

The sample above is using [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) to access Sheets API. You have to [enable this service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) in order to run this successfully.

Comment: @ lamblichus thanks for the solution... In place of using excludeUsers can we use Spreadsheet.addEditor, to keep the discussion more clear am posting a separate question for the same.